# Magento2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 121

Tags: magento2, product, json

Product detail page showing this error for some products

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 121<br>
   at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
   at getData (main.js:58)
   at Array.map (<anonymous>)
   at HTMLDocument.apply (main.js:74)
   at fire (jquery.js:3232)
   at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3362)
   at Function.ready (jquery.js:3582)
   at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.js:3617)
```

Please help me to fix this....

Comment: hey please mark my answers if solve your issue

Comment: No luck.  Error still there.

Comment: deploy content again

Answer (score 1):

So, since you did not specify the code, the error indicates that there are invalid tags in JSON, you need to look in JS for non-closed constructions.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace this**
app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml

**With this file**
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by renaming the following file:

```
app/design/frontend/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml
```

to

```
app/design/frontend/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/_gallery.phtml
```

After that run all magento commands.